# The children outside container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why is child outside container in flex display? I tried to solve the problem but it's not working

```css
/* ------------------------------------------- */
* {
    font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #f6f6f9;
}

/* ------------------------------------------- */
.container {
    background-color: orange;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
}

.card {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.test1 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.test2 {
    width: auto;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/home_css.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="test1" style="background-color: #ef5777;"></div>
        <p class="test2"></p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Orange = container  ~ the else is children.........................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Because you have set a fixed height to the `.card` and percentage height to the `.test2`. Provide an image for you expected outcome so that someone can help you with what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Flexbox` children can only be immediate children of a flex parent. `.card` is the immediate child of `.container`, the flex parent. From this screenshot, you should notice how the children of `.card` are stacking and spilling outside of `.container, but they are *not* flex children. This is expected behavior.
[image]

To keep the children of `.card` inside `.container`, make `.card` a flex parent as well, with columnar direction.

[image]

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #f6f6f9;
}

/* ------------------------------------------- */

.container {
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;             /* <- Added */
  flex-direction: column;    /* <- Added */
}

.test1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.test2 {
  width: auto;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="test1" style="background-color: #ef5777;"></div>
    <p class="test2"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvLuz6js/1/)

Comment: but the red child has text when I put text in center will disappears

Comment: @muco2 Right, because you have a fixed height on the `div`. You would need to add `overflow: auto` to `test2` or rethink your layout. Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xz7qdnks/) of this.

Comment: test2 has height: 50%; so should take 50% from parent not all screen ?

Comment: @muco2 How do you want it to behave? What is the goal?

Comment: I'm a bit distracted I'll try to understand it and thank you

Comment: Percentage heights required `height` to be set on a containing block of the element with the percentage height. This is often the immediate parent of the element with the percentage height.

Answer (score 0):

- `.card` has a fixed height of 200px.
- `.test1` has a fixed height of 150px.
- `.test2` has a height of 50% which will be 100px because height was set on its parent (`.card`).

`.test2` is overflowing `.card` because: `150px + 100px > 200px`. `.container` is only going to see the height of `.card`.